# Label in Catalog view for Special Price (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, special-price

I want to put a label for Special Price in caltalog view. Therefore I tried some code from final_price.phtml like this:

```
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    test
<?php endif; ?>
```

I try to use it in my list.phtml here:

```
app/design/frontend/name/theme/Magento_Caltalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

But it doesen't work that way here. How ist the the correct if statement to do that in list.phtml?

Answer (score 1):

I replaced block with product, now it works that way:

```
<?php if (($_product->getSpecialPrice())): ?>test<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First try this in the same file :

```
<?php
echo $product->getCustomAttribute();
?>
```

If you get the expected output then you can just override that particular file.

Comment: I get an error: Notice: Undefined variable: product in /home/zizzowa1/public_html/app/design/frontend/zizzo/MinimalBlack/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml on line 79
#0 /home/zizzowa1/public_html/app/design/frontend/zizzo/MinimalBlack/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml(79): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/home/zizzowa1/...', 79, Array)

Comment: What is the `attribute_code` of your Custom Attribute?